# setTimeout and the syntax with promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

I am reading a book on javascript and there is a piece of code that I don't understand.

```
setTimeout( () => setTimeout(console.log, 0 , value *2), 1000);
```

What exactly is happening here? There are two setTimeout, and I think I only understand the inner one. I don't understand what () => function is doing? Can you explain?

I do follow:

```
setTimeout(console.log, 0 , value *2)
```

which is passing the argument 'value*2' to function/method console.log() after 0 milli seconds. I also understand that setTimeout() return the timeoutId.

I don't know the rest.

I see something similar with the following code:

```
let p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve());
setTimeout(console.log, 0, p1);  //Promise <resolved>
```

Don't understand this either.

Comment: That's an arrow function. So, it's a `setTimeout` that takes 1 second to fire the arrow function within, which returns another `setTimeout`  *(since there are no `{}`)*, which fires `console.log` after 0 milliseconds passing `value*2` to it.

Comment: Is this homework?  I ask because, other than the educational explanation, this is pointless code - no reason to ever do this.  You can get the same result with a single `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Oh, I should state that `setTimeout` does return a `timeoutID`, but it fires the function that is passed to its first argument based on the second argument's milliseconds *(Asynchronously)*. All additional arguments are passed to your function argument.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout( () => setTimeout(console.log, 0 , value *2), 1000);` sets a timeout to... set a timeout. So after the the outer timeout finishes after 1 second, the inner function (`() => {...}` is an arrow function, which you can read as `function() {...}` for now) is called. This function sets another timeout with a delay of 0, which then calls console.log, passing `value * 2` as a parameter. Thus, after 1 second, `value * 2` is logged to the console.

With the Promise code, the line `let p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve());` creates a Promise which is immediately resolved. Thus on the next line when the promise is logged to the console, it shows `Promise<resolved>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(console.log, 0 , value *2)
```

is same as

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log(value *2) }, 0)
```

so

```
setTimeout( () => setTimeout(console.log, 0 , value *2), 1000);
```

means to set a timeout for one second, that will set another timeout for 0 second, and print `value *2`

```
let p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve());
setTimeout(console.log, 0, p1);
```

means to print out the promise `p1` after 0 second